# How do I set the type of reference for the list?

Tags: java, types, casting

I am a Java newbie. I need to define a constructor `MyArrayList(Object type)` to set the type of reference to be added later on to the list.

The **signature** of the constructor **can not be changed**. Also I'm **not allowed** to use **generics**.

I try do it like this:

```
public class MyArrayList implements MyList {
private Object[] theList; // array of objects


public MyArrayList(Object type) {
    theList = new type[0];

}
```

and get a compile error since `type` is no class. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Use generics and ditch the constructor completely.

Comment: *"and get a compile error"* - always post us the full error you get. Otherwise you will shrink your audience to people that immediately know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said that you **don't want** to use **generics**, you can create arrays dynamically via `Array#newInstance` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int-)). Here is your adjusted code:

```
public class MyArrayList implements MyList {
    private Object[] theList;

    public MyArrayList(Object type) {
        // Adjust as you like
        int size = 0;
        // Dynamically create array of type "type"
        theList = (Object[]) Array.newInstance(type.getClass(), size);
    }
}
```

Since you don't know the class at compile time you can only use it as `Object[]` however it will only allow elements of the true type of `type` at runtime, once the type is known, not arbitrary `Object`s.

---

Note that **arrays** are of **fixed size**. You can't just add elements to them, the size is always fixed and must be known in advance. If you need a more dynamic structure use something like `List` (`ArrayList` or `LinkedList` for example).

You can then just remember the given `type` object and if a user tries to add an item you check for `element instanceof type` and only add if that returns `true`, otherwise throw an exception like `IllegalArgumentException` or so.

Or alternatively, as said, set a good fixed size for your array. You can also give that choice to the user by providing an `size` parameter in your constructor.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to implement your solution, but I get a compiler error "Type mismatch" when I dynamically create an array. 'newInstance' returns an Object and 'theList' is Object[].

Comment: @abovady I've edited the code and added a cast to `Object[]` since the method returns an `Object` instead the array (but the true type actually is the array). Can you try it again?

Comment: Thank you, it worked. The size of my array is flexible. I add elements to the end of the array if the added element exceeds the boundaries. I do it by creating a new array with length+1 and copying the content of the old array to a new array.

Comment: @abovady Yeah, that works but is inefficient. `List` implementations like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` do it more clever such that `add` works in (averaged) constant time whereas your approach always needs linear time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to such scenario in Java is "generics".
The official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) for java is nice place to learn about generics.

For this scenario you can write the code as follows

The **List** interface

```
package test.generics;

public interface MyList<T> {
    T get(int index);
    void add(T input);
    void clear();
}
```

The **implementation**

```
package test.generics;

public class MyArrayList<T> implements MyList<T> {

    private Object[] storage = new Object[10];
    private int index = 0;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        T temp = null;
        if (!(index < 10 && index >= 0)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected range 0 to 9");
        } else {
            temp = (T) storage[index];
        }
        return temp;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T input) {
        if (index < 10) {
            storage[index++] = input;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only 10 items supported");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        index = 0;
    }

}
```

The **consumer**

```
package test.generics;

public class Consumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyList<Integer> intList = new MyArrayList<>();
        intList.add(10);
        System.out.println(intList.get(0));
        MyList<String> stringList = new MyArrayList<>();
        stringList.add("hello");
        System.out.println(stringList.get(0));
    }

}
```

Comment: I understand your solution but I am not allowed to use a type parameter. I have to use a constructor with the signature I described.